# Better template for report, Header and footer

Tags: header-footer

Need a better template for my reports, in this one the above logo stay in paragraph  space, and the footer is only in the margin space.

```
\documentclass[3pt,a4paper,showtrims]{article}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{lastpage}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%

\begin{document}%
\pagestyle{fancy}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
\rhead{\includegraphics[scale=.4]{Imagens/park-logo.png}}

\\%
\\%
\\%
text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me 
text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me 
\\
\\
text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me 
\\
\\
text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me 
text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me 
text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me text me 






\fancyfoot[L]{ 
   \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Imagens/park-footer.png}
}


\pagenumbering{gobble}%
\end{document}
```

[image]